# LocalStorage - Seperate Selections

Tags: menu, selection, drop

"Any optimization suggestions for js localstorage ?"

```js
$(function () {
    $('#selection1').change(function () {
        localStorage.setItem('todoData', this.value);
    });
    if (localStorage.getItem('todoData')) {

        $('#selection1').val(localStorage.getItem('todoData')).trigger('change');
    }
});


$(function () {
    $('#selection2').change(function () {
        localStorage.setItem('todoData2', this.value);
    });
    if (localStorage.getItem('todoData2')) {

        $('#selection2').val(localStorage.getItem('todoData2')).trigger('change');
    }
});

$(function () {
    $('#selection3').change(function () {
        localStorage.setItem('todoData3', this.value);
    });
    if (localStorage.getItem('todoData3')) {

        $('#selection3').val(localStorage.getItem('todoData3')).trigger('change');
    }
});

$(function () {
    $('#selection4').change(function () {
        localStorage.setItem('todoData4', this.value);
    });
    if (localStorage.getItem('todoData4')) {

        $('#selection4').val(localStorage.getItem('todoData4')).trigger('change');
    }
});

$(function () {
    $('#selection5').change(function () {
        localStorage.setItem('todoData5', this.value);
    });
    if (localStorage.getItem('todoData5')) {

        $('#selection5').val(localStorage.getItem('todoData5')).trigger('change');
    }
});

$(function () {
    $('#selection6').change(function () {
        localStorage.setItem('todoData6', this.value);
    });
    if (localStorage.getItem('todoData6')) {

        $('#selection6').val(localStorage.getItem('todoData6')).trigger('change');
    }
});

$(function () {
    $('#selection7').change(function () {
        localStorage.setItem('todoData7', this.value);
    });
    if (localStorage.getItem('todoData7')) {

        $('#selection7').val(localStorage.getItem('todoData7')).trigger('change');
    }
});

$(function () {
    $('#selection8').change(function () {
        localStorage.setItem('todoData8', this.value);
    });
    if (localStorage.getItem('todoData8')) {

        $('#selection8').val(localStorage.getItem('todoData8')).trigger('change');
    }
});

$(function () {
    $('#selection9').change(function () {
        localStorage.setItem('todoData9', this.value);
    });
    if (localStorage.getItem('todoData9')) {

        $('#selection9').val(localStorage.getItem('todoData9')).trigger('change');
    }
});

$(function () {
    $('#selection10').change(function () {
        localStorage.setItem('todoData10', this.value);
    });
    if (localStorage.getItem('todoData10')) {

        $('#selection10').val(localStorage.getItem('todoData10')).trigger('change');
    }
});

$(function () {
    $('#selection11').change(function () {
        localStorage.setItem('todoData11', this.value);
    });
    if (localStorage.getItem('todoData11')) {

        $('#selection11').val(localStorage.getItem('todoData11')).trigger('change');
    }
});

$(function () {
    $('#selection12').change(function () {
        localStorage.setItem('todoData12', this.value);
    });
    if (localStorage.getItem('todoData12')) {

        $('#selection12').val(localStorage.getItem('todoData12')).trigger('change');
    }
});

$(function () {
    $('#selection13').change(function () {
        localStorage.setItem('todoData13', this.value);
    });
    if (localStorage.getItem('todoData13')) {

        $('#selection13').val(localStorage.getItem('todoData13')).trigger('change');
    }
});
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.min.js"></script> 
<script type="text/javascript" src="pieteicejs.js"></script>
</head>
<select id="selection1">
    <option>1</option>
    <option>2</option>
    <option>3</option>
</select><br></br>

<select id="selection2">
    <option>4</option>
    <option>5</option>
    <option>6</option>
</select><br></br>

<select id="selection3">
    <option>7</option>
    <option>8</option>
    <option>9</option>
</select><br></br>

<select id="selection4">
    <option>10</option>
    <option>11</option>
    <option>12</option>
</select><br></br>

<select id="selection5">
    <option>13</option>
    <option>14</option>
    <option>15</option>
</select><br></br>

<select id="selection6">
    <option>16</option>
    <option>17</option>
    <option>18</option>
</select><br></br>

<select id="selection7">
    <option>19</option>
    <option>20</option>
    <option>21</option>
</select><br></br>

<select id="selection8">
    <option>22</option>
    <option>23</option>
    <option>24</option>
</select><br></br>


<select id="selection9">
    <option>25</option>
    <option>26</option>
    <option>27</option>
</select><br></br>

<select id="selection10">
    <option>28</option>
    <option>29</option>
    <option>30</option>
</select><br></br>

<select id="selection11">
    <option>31</option>
    <option>32</option>
    <option>33</option>
</select><br></br>

<select id="selection12">
    <option>34</option>
    <option>35</option>
    <option>36</option>
</select><br></br>

<select id="selection13">
    <option>37</option>
    <option>38</option>
    <option>39</option>
</select><br></br>
```

"How can I separate drop down menu from each other in order so they both save in Localstorage"

"How can I separate drop down menu from each other in order so they both save in Localstorage"

"How can I separate drop down menu from each other in order so they both save in Localstorage"

Comment: Your example is quite big, but the 4th, 5th, ... select does not change anything regards your question. Since you're new take this as advise: Reduce your example to the minimum without forgetting any detail the community should be aware of.

Comment: By the way  `<br>` has no ending tag (see https://www.w3schools.com/TAGS/tag_br.asp)

Comment: Thank you leun4m.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

LocalStorage is basically a key - value storage, for more information read this at [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/localStorage)

```js
// Assuming you have a clear localStorage...
localStorage.getItem('score')     // -> null

// The first setItem will create a new entry 
localStorage.setItem('score', 5)
localStorage.getItem('score')     // -> 5

// Any next setItem on the same key will overwrite the data
localStorage.setItem('score', 10)
localStorage.getItem('score')     // -> 10
```

So, if you want to save both dropdowns separate, you will have to use different names, e.g.

```js
// SELECT 1
localStorage.setItem('todoData1', this.value);
localStorage.getItem('todoData1');
// SELECT 2
localStorage.setItem('todoData2', this.value);
localStorage.getItem('todoData2');
```

**Edit: (after question change)**

To achieve this for a list of selects, you might prefer declaring that using a loop:

```js
$(function() {
  for (let i = 0; i < 13; i++) {
    const storageName = `todoData${i}`;
    const selectionId = `#selection${i}`;
    $(selectionId).change(function() {
        localStorage.setItem(storageName, this.value);
    });
    // to save data initially
    if (!localStorage.getItem(storageName)) {
        $(selectionId).trigger('change');
    }
  }
});
```

Comment: Thanks leun4m for reply. Any optimization suggestions for my current js localstorage?

Comment: If this answered your question, please consider marking it as your accepted answer.

Comment: When I add line - "<link rel="stylesheet" href="bootstrap.min.css">" then it doesn't save on exit, but only while session is active. It doesn't seem to like CSS however I need it for design.

Comment: A stylesheet shouldn't change anything at all and when I tried, it didn't: https://plnkr.co/edit/WzxzRfLTrWpr5EZn

Comment: Thank you @leun4m for your input. I appreciate it. It seems that issue was the ''Microsoft Edge" browser. On "Firefox" everything works perefect.